# resignFirstResponder and close keyboard from anywhere?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a situation where the keyboard maybe open and then an NSTimer pops a view over the text view. Is there anyway to close the keyboard globally rather than from the text view resignFirstResponder method? The reason I ask is that the textView is dynamic in that it maybe there sometimes and not others. One way would be to give it a TAG. Can multiple items be referenced with same tag?

I think the answer is no but I would be interested in your thoughts?

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The endEditing: method of UIView should do the trick. Send it to the superview of the potentially existing UITextView when you want to dismiss the keyboard.

Comment: I did not know about that method very handy!!

Answer (score 7):

To dismiss the keyboard from **anywhere**, even if you don't know directly who is the firstResponder, use:

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] endEditing:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to send some control the message becomeFirstResponder

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a reference to the UITextView in the NSTimer...

ORRRRR....

In the view that pops up you could do something like:

```
for(id view in self.superview.subviews){
    [(UIView *)view resignFirstResponder];
}
```